# MySQL Stored Procedure schedule specific time

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

How is it possible to call a procedure in a certain period of time, which calculates certain values, updates the existing value?
Let's assume that from 06:00 - 08:00 a certain procedure should be executed every minute. This should then be paused from 08:00 - 08:15 and then start again from 08:15 - 11:30 and so on.  That from Monday to Friday and Saturday to Sunday it should be paused.

My question thus, how can I let this certain procedure run at the certain times?

Comment: [Using the Event Scheduler](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/event-scheduler.html)

Comment: I see two questions here. One about a specific task (calculating some values) and one about scheduling that task. If you focus on one question per post, you should have better luck getting any answer.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Create a scheduled event](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-event.html) that runs every minute and use a conditional statement in the event to determine whether to run the proc based on [`DAYOFWEEK`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_dayofweek) and [`CURRENT_TIME`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_current-time):

```sql
DELIMITER //

CREATE EVENT `my_event`
ON SCHEDULE
    EVERY 1 MINUTE
    STARTS CURRENT_DATE
DO
    IF (
        DAYOFWEEK(CURRENT_DATE) BETWEEN 2 AND 6 AND
        (
            CURRENT_TIME BETWEEN '06:00:00' AND '08:00:00' OR
            CURRENT_TIME BETWEEN '08:15:00' AND '11:30:00' -- and so on
        )
    )
    THEN CALL certain_procedure();
    END IF;
//

DELIMITER ;
```

When running an event this frequently, you may want to implement some kind of locking (see [`GET_LOCK()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/locking-functions.html#function_get-lock)) if there is any chance of your proc taking longer than a minute to execute.

Comment: thanks for the reply, but it's not working. I changed the part "certain_procedure();" to "myProcedureName();" and it's not getting called. Even when I change the time.

Comment: Update your question with what you have done. Please include the output of `SHOW CREATE EVENT your_event_name;` and check the status of the new event with `SHOW EVENTS;`. Also, check your MySQL error log for relevant entries.

Comment: The Error Log helped.. I did a new installation of my System and forget to turn back on the global_event_scheduler. Thanks for your help. Is there a way also to use this IF statement just for a single day?

Comment: Yes, just change the `DAYOFWEEK()` criterion. Link included in answer above.